# AVPlayerViewController tapping "done" dismiss to wrong view controller

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller with a view controller (call it A) containing a tableview. I tap on an item in the tableview and I'm taken to a new view controller, call it B. In B I present AVPlayerViewController and when done viewing I tap done and it's dismissed all the way back to vc A (instead of B). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably when you press done the navigationController is "popViewController" to the first on the stack.

Comment: It's just standard... I call Presentviewcontroller(avPlayerVc...) in B

Comment: The 'Done' button acts as a dismissal for a modal presentation style. Since you presented it as modal with "presentViewController". My advice is push the AVPlayerViewController onto the navigation stack and handle the popping yourself.

Comment: Diogo how can I override the "done" action on AVPlayerViewController?

Comment: Instead of "presentViewController" push the AVPlayerController to the navigationStack with "navigationController.pushViewController()", that will make it so that the AVPlayerViewController will not present a "Done" UIButton

Comment: @DiogoAntunes well it should be presented modally so I'm stuck with "presentViewController..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen` did the trick

Comment: @RhythmicFistman nope not until tomorrow (SO laws disallows me)